# is it possible to create web application using c++ in visual-studio-2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I had created media annotation application which is a dialog based MFC application using c++ in visual studio2010. I want to make it work using web application by accessing it through URL via web browser.Is it possible to implement through C++?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. In stead of using the dialog based application, create automation COM component and use that in html or scripting languages.